# Best method for cloning a github repository to another github repository

Tags: github

I'm new to git and GitHub so sorry if this question is simplistic. A vendor has developed the WordPress theme for our website and has created GitHub repo of the theme. We want to clone the theme to our an organization which has been set up on our enterprise GitHub account. However, I'm not quite understanding the process for the process for doing this. When I search cloning it's the answer always is discusses cloning from a GitHub repo to a local repo, whereas we want to clone from a private GitHub repo to a repo in the setup in our organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferring a repo would mean you are the owner of the original repo.

If you are not the owner of that vendor theme repository, you do have to clone it locally, and then:

- change its remote to refer to a new empty repo created in your GitHub organisation
- push everything

That is:

```
git clone --mirror git@github.com:user/repo.git
cd repo.git
git remote set-url origin git@yourGitHUb.com:org/empty-repo.git
git push --mirror
```

Comment: I ended up discussing these approaches with the lead dev, and we went with a similar process to what you outlined here. The main difference was to use --bare on with the clone. Then, once i CDed into the repo.git folder I used **git remote add enterprise** , and then **git push enterprise --mirror**.

Comment: @C_Angell A `git clone --mirror` *is* a bare repo anyway.

Comment: But here's where I'm still having an issue. 

When I go to the remote on our enterprise account I see all of the theme files that I would expect. But on the local repo (the repo.git folder from the initial clone using --bare) I only see the .git folder but none of the expected theme files. And if I CD into repo.git and run the command  **git checkout master** I get an error - **fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree**

So on a conceptual level what i don't understand is, now that I have the remote established on github, what do I need to do to work on it locally.

Comment: @C_Angell That is expected: a bare repo has no file/working tree: you don't need to checkout master, only to set a new remote and push.

Comment: Great advice. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,I guess you need to transfer the ownership of the repo. You can refer this

https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-a-repository/

Hope this helps!

EDIT 1:If you just need a copy of the original repo (Note: further changes in original repo will not reflect in yours unless you do a pull after forking it)

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/